# Calculate the following limit is $1$.

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

> Let $m(n)=\min\{m:2^{-m}m^{-3/2}\leq n^{-1}\}$. Then  $$
>  \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^{m(n)}\log_{2}n}{n}=1. $$

This problem is a piece of solving : [An unfair "fair game."](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454282/an-unfair-fair-game)

Comment: This problem is wrong. It should be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
\frac{1}{2^m m^{3/2}} \approx \frac{1}{n},
$$
or equivalently,
$$
2^m m^{3/2} \approx n
$$
and taking logs,
$$
m + \frac{3}{2} \log m \approx \log n
$$
So
$$
\frac{n}{\log n} \approx \frac{2^m m^{3/2}}{m + \frac{3}{2} \log m}
$$

Comment: Sorry but could you check my question again? I edited it just before you answer.

Comment: @kayak same idea, seems like a bug of a sorts...

Comment: I got to your final line. But how does that imply the answer of my question?

Comment: @kayak if you know what $n/\lg n$ is, can you compute $2^m \ln n/n$?

Comment: From your final line, $$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^{m(n)}\log n}{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{m+\frac{3}{2}\log m}{m^{3/2}}.
$$
Then it converges to 0. So this is not what I want to get.

Comment: @kayak my point exactly, hence the line `seems like a bug of sorts` in my earlier comment...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56241/discussion-between-kayak-and-gt6989b).