# A question about weak law for triangular arrays

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, statistics

This is from Durrett(2.2.8). Let $p_k = \frac{1}{2^k k(k+1)}$, $k=1,2,..$  and $p_0 = 1-\sum_k p_k$. $X_i$ are $iid$ with $P(X_n = -1) = p_0$ and $$P(X_n = 2^k - 1) = p_k \text{  for  }  k\geq 1$$
Note $EX_n = 0$ and let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k$ Use theorem $2.2.6$ with $b_n = 2^{m(n)}$ where $m(n)=min\{m|2^{-m}m^{-3/2}\leq n^{-1}\}$ to conclude that $S_n/(n/\log_2 n)\rightarrow -1$.

Theorem 2.2.6 : If $b_n> 0$ with $b_n\rightarrow \infty$ and $\tilde{X}_{n,k}=X_{n,k}.1_{|X_{n,k}\leq b_n|}$ and with $n\rightarrow \infty$ if
(i) $\sum_{k=1}^{n}P(|X_{n,k}|>b_n)\rightarrow 0$
(ii) $b_n^{-2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} E\tilde{X}_{n,k}^2 \rightarrow 0$

the above hold, then $(S_n - E\tilde{X}_{n,k})/b_n \xrightarrow{p} 0$

I've proved (i), for (ii):

$$b_n^{-2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} E\tilde{X}_{n,k}^2 = (2^{-m(n)})^2.n.E\tilde{X}_{1}^{2} = n.4^{-m(n)}.E|X_1|^2.1_{|X_1|\leq 2^{m(n)}} =$$

$$n.4^{-m(n)}.[p_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{m(n)}\frac{(2^{k}-1)^2}{2^k k(k+1)}] < n.4^{-m(n)}.[p_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{m(n)}\frac{(2^{k})^2}{2^k k(k+1)}] =$$

$$n.4^{-m(n)}.[p_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{m(n)}\frac{2^k}{k(k+1)}]\leq n.4^{-m(n)}.2^{m(n)}.[p_0.2^{-m(n)} + \int_{k=1}^{m(n)}\frac{dx}{x^2}] =$$

$$\text{Consider } n.2^{-m(n)}.\int_{1}^{m(n)}\frac{dx}{x^2} = n.2^{-m(n)}.[1-\frac{1}{m(n)}] = n.2^{-m(n)} - n.2^{-m(n)}.m(n)^{-1}\text{ -(*)}$$

$n.2^{-m(n)} = n.m(n)^{3/2}.m(n)^{-3/2}.2^{-m(n)}\leq m(n)^{3/2}$ and thus (*) $\leq m(n)^{3/2}-m(n)^{1/2}$

and since $m(n)\rightarrow \infty$, I do not have proper upper bound that $\rightarrow 0$. A hint is appreciated to find an upper bound that $\rightarrow 0$. Thanks.

Comment: This is the same question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454282/an-unfair-fair-game?rq=1